# GET/POST requests from Nodejs to Google App Engine not working

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, axios, node-fetch

Trying to migrate some resources from Cloud functions to App Engine.

Problem: When I send a request from another Nodejs server to app deployed to App Engine,

```
await axios.get("https://project-id.uc.r.appspot.com/hey")
```

it gives error:

```
(node:13088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
project-id.uc.r.appspot.com project-id.uc.r.appspot.com:443
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
```

What I've tried and verified:

1. Requests from Nodejs -> App Engine fail
2. Requests from Browser -> App Engine pass
3. Replaced Axios with node-fetch, still same error.

Update:

Everything seems to be working as expected when I connected custom domain name.

A problem with Nodejs not being able to resolve "x.y.z.appspot.com" domain? Kinda sus.

Comment: Are those App Engine services deployed in standard environment or flexible environment?

Comment: Standard environment (F2)

Comment: Is you other node server also in App Engine? Or where is it running? If it's running on App Engine, you can try to call the explicit version and service as indicated on [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/communicating-between-services) `https://VERSION_ID-dot-SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com`.

Comment: Cloud functions as well as localhost (Express), same error in both environments.

Comment: Can you try npm install express?